# Azure AD B2C social sign-in with OAuth2 Provider

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c

Kinda new to this area of customizable sign-in/sign-up.

I'm currently planning to use social sing-in/sign-up in my Web API project, that handles backend process for my Web App and Desktop Client. I found it is easy [to add a OpenID Connect provider to my Identity Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-oidc-idp), but am not sure how can I add OAuth2 provider. Is there a good example or tutorial on this topic?

Also, according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-oauth-code) and [that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-oidc) post, it is recommended to use OAuth2 for native apps and OpenID Connect for Web API/Web Apps. Unfortunately the organization whose authentication I'd like to let customers use doesn't provide OpenID Connect. Is this still fine for my scenario?

Answer (score 1):

This [sample](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-oauth2-useridentity/) should be able to help you achieve what you are looking for. It uses the OAuth2.0 authorization code grant with confidential client and ADAL to obtain access tokens for the web app to call the Graph API with the user's identity.

This reference on [authentication scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#web-application-to-web-api) should also be useful to you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, the tutorial is on calling an api via Azure AD. Looking at the things in the portal, there seems some difference in the practice for Azure AD **B2C**. Can I think the content of this and any tutorials talking about AD applicable to B2C anyway?

Comment: And the second link about authentication scenarios looks useful, thanks.